# Bash Script sed command not working correctly with file passed through command line

Tags: regex, bash, unicode, sed

## Problem

As I am trying to write a script to rename massive files according to some regex requirement, the command work ok on my iTerm2 succeeds but the same command fails to do the work in the script.

Plus some of my file names includes some Chinese and Korean characters.(don't know whether that is the problem or not)

## code

So My code takes three input: Old regex, New regex and the files that need to be renamed.

Here is not code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# we have less than 3 arguments. Print the help text:
if [ $# -lt 3 ] ; then
  cat << HELP
ren -- renames a number of files using sed regular expressions USAGE: ren 'regexp'
'replacement' files...

EXAMPLE: rename all *.HTM files into *.html:
ren 'HTM' 'html' *.HTM

HELP
  exit 0
fi

OLD="$1"
NEW="$2"
# The shift command removes one argument from the list of
# command line arguments.
shift
shift
# $@ contains now all the files:
for file in "$@"; do
  if [ -f "$file" ] ; then
    newfile=`echo "$file" | sed "s/${OLD}/${NEW}/g"`
    if [ -f "$newfile" ]; then
      echo "ERROR: $newfile exists already"
    else
      echo "renaming $file to $newfile ..."
      mv "$file" "$newfile"
    fi
  fi
done
```

I register the bash command in the *.profile* as:

```
alias ren="bash /pathtothefile/ren.sh"
```

## Test

The original file name is "제01과.mp3" and I want it to become "第01课.mp3".

So with my script I use:

```
$ ren "제\([0-9]*\)과" "第\1课" *.mp3
```

And it seems that the *sed* in the script has not worked successfully.

But the following which is exactly the same, works to replaces the name:

```
$ echo "제01과.mp3" | sed s/"제\([0-9]*\)과\.mp3"/"第\1课\.mp3"/g
```

Any thoughts? Thx

## Print the result

I have make the following change in the script so that it could print the process information:

```
newfile=`echo "$file" | sed "s/${OLD}/${NEW}/g"`
echo "The ${file} is changed to ${newfile}"
```

And the result for my test is:

```
The 제01과.mp3 is changed into 제01과.mp3
ERROR: 제01과.mp3 exists already
```

So there is no format problem.

## Updating(all done under bash 4.2.45(2), Mac OS 10.9)

### Testing

As I try to execute the command from the bash directly. I mean with the for loop. There is something interesting. I first stored all the names into a *files.txt* file using:

```
$ ls | grep mp3 > files.txt
```

And do the sed and bla bla. While single command in bash interactive mode like:

```
$ file="제01과.mp3"
$ echo $file | sed s/"제\([0-9]*\)과\.mp3"/"第\1课\.mp3"/g
```

gives

```
第01课.mp3
```

While in the following in the interactive mode:

```
files=`cat files.txt`
for file in $files
do
    echo $file | sed s/"제\([0-9]*\)과\.mp3"/"第\1课\.mp3"/g
done
```

gives no changes!

And by now:

```
echo $file
```

gives:

```
$ 제30과.mp3
```

(There are only 30 files)

### Problem Part

And I tried the first command which worked before:

```
$ echo $file | sed s/"제\([0-9]*\)과\.mp3"/"第\1课\.mp3"/g
```

It gives no changes as:

```
$ 제30과.mp3
```

So I create a new *newfile* and tried again as:

```
$ newfile="제30과.mp3"
$ echo $newfile | sed s/"제\([0-9]*\)과\.mp3"/"第\1课\.mp3"/g
```

And it gives correctly:

```
$第30课.mp3
```

WOW ORZ... Why! Why ! Why! And I try to see whether *file* and *newfile* are the same, and of course, they are not:

```
if [[ $file == $new ]]; then
    echo True
else
    echo False
fi
```

gives:

```
False
```

### My guess

I guess there are some encoding problems , but I have found non reference, could anyone help? Thx again.

## Update 2

I seem to understand that there are a huge difference between string and the file name. To be specific, it I directly use a variable like:

```
file="제30과.mp3"
```

in the script, the `sed` works fine. However, if the variable was passed from the $@ or set the variable like:

```
file=./*mp3
```

Then the `sed` fails to work. I don't know why. And btw, mac `sed` has no `-r` option and in ubuntu `-r` does not solve the question I mention above.

Comment: Searching here on S.O. for `[sed] unicode` returned 50 answers. I know I've seen similar questions answered before. Good luck.

Comment: The problem with your script has been identified in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20580167/2235132).  But you probably don't need a script.  You could pretty much achieve the same using `rename` (that is a part of Perl distribution).

Comment: Run your script with the `-x` option to see what goes wrong, as in `bash -x ren blabla`.

Comment: Thanks all. The indentation is fixed as all of you have suggested, but the script still will not work on my test example.

Comment: The indentation is a copy-and-post problem into OS. The script could run correctly. And let the script print out the result in the script, it is clear that the *newfile* is the same as the *file*

Comment: @Archimedes520 Nice script. Unless you're doing it for fun though, you might want to look into `rename` from the perl libraries http://man.he.net/man1/rename , which includes the same functionality and more.

Comment: Could not reproduce. Seems to work for me (`LANG=en_US.utf8`, GNU bash `v.4.2.45(1)`)

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Do you mean you use the script I give and try the example I give(the Chinese and Korean character)? I checked that My Bash is 3.24 so I upgrade it to 4.2.45 and set the locale to en_US.utf8. But when I do that, the command line could not even show the characters, let alone doing the sed. I change the LANG back to null and tried again and it is still not working. I wonder how you did it?

Comment: Yes, I used the Korean filename copied from your post and renamed it to the Chinese version using your script.  Also my sed is v. 4.2.1 all on OpenSUSE 12.2.

Comment: If you create an alias using `alias ren="sh /pathtothefile/ren.sh"`, you're running your script with `sh`, not with `bash`.

Comment: @Rubens Have change the alias to bash, I should update again.sorry, but still not working. I am using mac OS 10.9

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Could you give all the locale information for me? Thx a lot

Comment: Everything's set to en_US.utf8 here, i.e. `LANG=en_US.utf8 LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8" LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8" ...` but `LC_ALL=`

Comment: Why is the closing paranthesis escaped but not the dot? Did you mean: `s/"제\([0-9]+)과\\.mp3"/"第\1课.mp3"/g`

Comment: @kurellajunior I am sorry, I don't quite understand you. The parenthesis with backslash is to denote the number in the file name and use later.

Comment: Just in case you did not rename them by hand meanwhile, I updated my answer with a working solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some errors combined:

- In order to use groups in a regex, you need extended regex `-r` in sed, `-E` in grep
- escaping correctly is a beast :)

Example

```
files="제2과.mp3 제30과.mp3"
for file in $files
do
    echo $file | sed -r 's/제([0-9]*)과\.mp3/第\1课.mp3/g'
done
```

outputs

```
第2课.mp3
第30课.mp3
```

Comment: @Archimedes520 edited the answer. Now it's correct. Sorry for the nonsense before :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are not doing this as a programming project, but want to skip ahead to the part where it just works, I found these resources listed at http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x4055.htm:

- MMV (and MCP, MLN, ...) utilities use a specialized syntax to perform bulk file operations on paths. (http://linux.maruhn.com/sec/mmv.html)

  `mmv before\*after.mp3 Before\#1After.mp3`
- Esomaniac, a Java alternative that also works on Windows, is apparently dead (home page is parked).
- rename is a perl script you can download from CPAN: https://metacpan.org/release/File-Rename

  `rename 's/\.JPG$/.jpg/' *.JPG`